# O que significa txuca txuca bom bom? E em que situação se usa 'eish'?

Tags: significado

What does this mean in European Portuguese?

Comment: Onde é que encontraste esse "txuca txuca" e o "eish"? Podes incluir a citação e link, se estiver na net?

Comment: Está falando disso? http://media.rtp.pt/5meianoite/pressao-no-ar/david-carreira-agressivo-eish/
Foi a única menção que encontrei.

Comment: Parecem 2 perguntas, uma sendo sobre o "txuca txuca" e outra sobre o "eish". Mesmo assim falta um contexto e atè mesmo uma padronização, já que o título está em Português e o corpo da pergunta em Inglês!

Comment: A. Silva, a ideia dos comentadores foi encorajar-te a melhorar a pergunta: clicar no "edit" e pôr tudo na mesma língua, e escrever qualquer coisa do tipo, "Encontrei neste artigo esta expressão, tal e tal..."; incluir o link e o texto envolvente. Se precisares de ajuda, diz. Se fizeres isso, com certeza os votos negativos irão desaparecer.

Answer (score 2):

Vou responder à pergunta saindo do pré-suposto que está relacionado a [isso](http://media.rtp.pt/5meianoite/pressao-no-ar/david-carreira-agressivo-eish/), pois é a única menção que encontrei na Internet.

> txuca txuca bom bom

No caso é uma pergunta:

> Com quantas mulheres já fizeste o txuca txuca bom bom?

Nesse contexto, *txuca txuca bom bom* tem o significado de *relação sexual*. Nesse caso, uma gíria.

Refazendo a pergunta, seria:

> Com quantas mulheres já tiveste relações sexuais?

Agora, vamos partir para o *Eish*:

> David Carreira: “Agressivo! Eish…”

Nesse caso, é uma expressão de espanto.

**In English:**

> Com quantas mulheres já fizeste o txuca txuca bom bom?

You could translate to (*txuca txuca bom bom* is a slang in this case):

> How many women did you have sex with?

The *Eish* is a exclamation of astonishment or surprise and it could be translated to:

> David Carreira: “Aggressive! OMG…”

Comment: lembrando que essas músicas dizem ter duplo sentido e o segundo sentido seria fazer a referida dança da música.